# Model comparison

Tags: r, dataframe

I  am trying to compare two model fits by using `DIC(Deviance information criterion)` using a for loop, but it returns

> Error argument is of length zero

in the else if line. here below is the code.

```
Data <- read.delim("A.txt")
a = Data[, 16]

if (isTRUE(MannKendall(a)[["p.value"]] > 0.05 &&
           Box.test(a, lag = 8, type = "Ljung-Box") [["p.value"]] > 0.05) &&
    pettitt.test(a)
    [["p.value"]] > 0.05 |
    kpss.test(log(a), null = "Trend")[["p.value"]] > 0.05) {
  fit1 <-
    fevd(a, Data, method = "Bayesian", units = "mm")
  print(return.level(fit1, return.period = c(25, 50, 100)))
  rp = c(25, 50, 100)
  print(ci(fit1, return.period = c(25, 50, 100)))
  
} else if (fevd(a,
                Data,
                method = "Bayesian",
                location.fun = ~ ti,
                units = "mm")[["DIC"]] < fevd(
                  a,
                  Data,
                  method = "Bayesian",
                  location.fun = ~ ti,
                  scale.fun = ~ ti,
                  use.phi = TRUE,
                  na.action = na.fail,
                  units = "mm"
                )[["DIC"]]) {
  fit2 <-
    fevd(
      a,
      Data,
      method = "Bayesian",
      location.fun = ~ ti,
      units = "mm"
    )
  print(return.level(fit2, return.period = c(25)))
  print(return.level(fit2, return.period = c(50)))
  print(return.level(fit2, return.period = c(100))):rp = c(25, 50, 100, 150)
  print(ci(fit2, return.period = c(25)))
  
} else {
  fit3 <-
    fevd(
      a,
      Data,
      method = "Bayesian",
      location.fun = ~ ti,
      scale.fun = ~ ti,
      use.phi = TRUE,
      na.action = na.fail,
      units = "mm"
    )
  print(return.level(fit3, return.period = c(25)))
  print(return.level(fit3, return.period = c(50)))
  print(return.level(fit3, return.period = c(100))):rp = c(25, 50, 100)
  print(ci(fit3, return.period = c(25)))
  
}
```

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rjj4ocWcxi4U3lDQiSQvwRaviWea2X1E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: fevd(a, Data, method = "Bayesian", location.fun = ~ti, units = "mm")[["DIC"]] < fevd(a, Data, method = "Bayesian",location.fun = ~ti, scale.fun = ~ti,use.phi =TRUE,na.action = na.fail, units = "mm")[["DIC"]]                             returns argument length zero error

Comment: Please take a bit of time to format and read  the "help" on writing questions before posting a question. Using `ctrl+a` followed by `ctrl+shift+a` in Rstudio will automatically format your code into something that is generally more readable. I have done this for now, and reduced your text a bit. Your link is also broken, as the file is not shared with anyone who has the link. I don't know the content of the file, but it is generally discouraged to link to content, as the link may "break" later, making the question harder to understand for future readers. Instead embed the content in your post.